# Android Async Task execution

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

In android async tasks, is all the code executed sequentially, or there are some optimizations? I ask because I experienced a strange behaviour with batch of ContentProviderOperations to execute in the asynct task. I am asking for the doInBackground method as the other two are executed on the ui thread.

EDIT: The strange behaviour is the following: I have three tables, one has its primary key as foreign key int the other two, and the other two are independent between each other. So when I want to delete something I go first with deleting the rows of the independent tables in order to remove the foreign key constraint in the first one, so I can delete it from there as well. For inserting the other way around, first I create the row in the 1st table, to create a primary key to which the other two can reference, and then I create the row in the other two.

All of this is put in batch of Content provider Operation, but I get a constraint failed response.

EDIT2: All of this in a single thread, in the doInBackground of a single AsyncTask and here is the code ( Problem is the one that has fk to the other two:

```
for (ActionSyncModel ac : res.actions_table) {
                    Uri deleteUri = ActionContract.Action.CONTENT_URI
                            .buildUpon()
                            .appendPath(Integer.toString(ac.oldId)).build();
                    String temp = deleteUri.toString();
                    Log.i("action delete ->>>> ", temp);
                    batch.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(deleteUri)
                            .build());
                    getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);
                }

                for (JournalAttachmentSyncModel js : res.attach_table) {

                    Uri deleteUri = JournalAttachmentContract.JournalAttachment.CONTENT_URI
                            .buildUpon()
                            .appendPath(Integer.toString(js.oldId)).build();
                    String temp = deleteUri.toString();
                    Log.i("attach delete ->>>>", temp);
                    batch.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(deleteUri)
                            .build());
                    getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);
                }

                for (ProblemSyncModel pro : res.problems_table) {

                    Uri deleteUri = ProblemContract.Problem.CONTENT_URI
                            .buildUpon()
                            .appendPath(Integer.toString(pro.oldId))
                            .build();
                    String temp = deleteUri.toString();
                    Log.i("problem delete->>>>", temp);
                    batch.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(deleteUri)
                            .build());
                    getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);
                }
```

Thank you

Comment: Google this, that would help more. Or pls specify what was the strange behavior, in your code - what is the code that you have tried. Can be more descriptive on what is expected and what is happening

Comment: As I know - not. There are no optimization in doInBackround. It simply executes your code in the background thread. You have mistake in your doInBackground method, I think. Or you execute something else in the same time.

Comment: Multiple AsyncTask are run sequentially by default if not run on a thread pool executor service.

Comment: I am not asking about multiple tasks, but for the code inside a single task.

Answer (score 0):

From the code above, it seems that the batch operation is not execute in the end. You need getContentResolver().applyBatch(...) to run it in bath. Otherwise, all the deletes are executed  independently in individual transaction instead of a single transaction.

But it may not necessarily explain the constraint error. It may help more with the schema.